# Steps to deinstall postgres

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, postgresql

I installed postgres. It created a user account. I don't need postgres anymore.
What are the steps I have to proceed to uninstall it completely from Ubuntu 14.04? (I didn't install the software over the Software-Center.

Comment: if not software center, then how? did you use apt-get or aptitude?

Comment: I think I did `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main` as mentioned here: http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/. I'm not sure though and I do not know where the source directory rests.

Comment: okay, there you go

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't find anything on the two first commands. However, I can see that there is a user PostgreSQL at the top right in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First:

execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge postgres
```

review the changes to be made and if you are happy accept the changes and continue.

Next:

remove the repository from /etc/apt/sources.list.d like so:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

Finally:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

done.

Comment: E: Paket postgres couldn't be found. There is a user called postgres however.

Comment: Okay, run `sudo apt-get install postgres` and then `sudo apt-get purge postgres`

Comment: Again the same message: `E: Paket postgres could not be found`